# Commands to Customize a New Block

Tags: make.com, roamresearch, roam-bot

You suggest <<[[Todo]]>> as a method for getting the checkbox inserted. Are there other techniques for other block formatting? For example, how to insert a new child block at the same time I post a to do? Other commands I want to use:

New block
Indent block
Formatting
Block/page embed

{{carriagereturn}} and {{tab}} in Make does create a new line and indent, but I am not able to create a new block.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.